# Yank whole file

Tags: vim, yank

I would like to setup a command to yank the whole file without moving the cursor.

Here is the macro I created:

```
qaggVGy
```

However, this moves the cursor to the beginning of the file. How can I yank the whole file without losing the cursors position ?

Comment: Do you mean /page/ or /file/? Your macro yanks the entire file.

Comment: What do you want to do with that yanked text?

Comment: I want to paste it on an other window. I have set up + as the default yank register

Comment: In general, if you want to execute some commands and then return the cursor to its previous position, just set a mark before running the commands `m'` then return to the mark at the end `\`'`. Just add those characters to the beginning and end of your macro.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I usually use `:%y+` to yank the complete file into the system clipboard. You can of course use any other register as you like.

Comment: or just `:%y` to yank to the default register like the OP did